# Ionic 2 - Include Authorization header in all api calls

Tags: http, angular, authorization, ionic2

My Ionic 2 app have few providers and they communicate with a secured API over http, so I have to include an authorization header contains bearer token (which I stored in localstorage) with every request I made.

My current (ugly) implementation is for each function, am appending header like below sample code,

```
getAccountDetails(accountId: string): Promise<any> {
    let url = API_ENDPOINT + 'some-string';
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.userData.hasLoggedIn().then((hasLoggedIn) => {
        if (hasLoggedIn) {
          this.userData.getUserToken().then((token) => {
            let headers = new Headers();

            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

            this.http.post(url, { id: accountId }, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
              resolve(data);
            });
          })
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

As I mentioned above, for each functions now I repeat the same header append code, how can I make it DRY (avoid repeating the same code)?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#override-default-request-options

Comment: Extend angular2 http class or create api service with parameterized http methods, for example: 
`get(path:String,unrestricted?:boolean) {
    var authHeader = new Headers();
    if(!unrestricted)
      authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token"));`